# How to properly implement summarise function via dplyr package using an excel (xlsx) file (R language)?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, xlsx

I am working on a project for work and while we currently use excel to perform data analysis, I'm trying to transition into R as I believe from my past experiences, this will prove far more useful and efficient in the long run. I attached two pictures, one showing the raw data that is being used and one showing the end result I want via Excel's pivot table. Note I changed names due to confidentiality. **Edit: I realize the result in Excel does not have equal dimensions as with the summarise function's output, should I be using a different function? Otherwise, I included a third picture that may be more feasible to achieve.** [Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vas7g.jpg) [Preferred result in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLA7L.jpg) [Second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBWiu.jpg)

Here is the code I have written so far (importing and creating data frame. mutating etc. has been successful so I didn't include it and rd_data1 is the original data imported with no changes):

```
rd_analysis2 <- rd_data1 %>%

  select('Employee Name', 'Month', 'Customer Name', 'Service Type', 'Number of Points', 'Actual Time Spent(min)', 'Work Order') %>%
    group_by('Employee Name', 'Month', 'Customer Name', 'Service Type') %>%
      summarise(Total_Points = sum('Number of Points', na.rm=TRUE), Total_Time = sum('Actual Time Spent(min)'), distinct_work_orders = n_distinct('Work Order')) %>%
        arrange('Employee Name', 'Month')
```

I either get error messages with the summarise function saying "Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `Total_Points`. x invalid 'type' (character) of argument" or get a weird result that combines all the points and time, but not grouped as I would like. Any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated as I'm a little rusty so please forgive me if I'm off in my syntax.

Comment: I can't recreate as raw data in in image format. However, typically if you get this type of error is due to calling a function that requires a number as input. So if your 'Total_points' was of character class this would happen. You may need to change class of the column.

Comment: Is it possible for me to upload the raw data on here? That's what I thought too, but when I did summary(rd_data1), it show's Number of Points column as a numeric imput and the same applies for time. Note "Total_Points" is simple a new variable I created not an input from the original source, I don't think it matters what the name of the variable is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're merely using the wrong quotation for your column names. Try using a backtick (`) instead.

```
rd_analysis2 <- rd_data1 %>%
  select(`Employee Name`, `Month`, `Customer Name`, `Service Type`, `Number of Points`, `Actual Time Spent(min)`, `Work Order`) %>%
  group_by(`Employee Name`, `Month`, `Customer Name`, `Service Type`) %>%
  summarise(
    Total_Points = sum(`Number of Points`, na.rm=TRUE),
    Total_Time = sum(`Actual Time Spent(min)`),
    distinct_work_orders = n_distinct(`Work Order`),

    .groups = 'drop'
  ) %>%
  arrange(`Employee Name`, `Month`)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted to compute and it worked perfectly. Much love my man, my skills are rusty after all. Quick question, I'm getting duplicate columns of employee name and month, with values being the same as the column names iterated over and over. Anyway to get rid of this?

Comment: Even though it shouldn't be that, perhaps it has to do with the result after summarise still being grouped by `Employee Name`, `Month` & `Customer Name`. I've added a `.groups = 'drop'` statement, which makes sure you come out with an ungrouped df. alternatively, you could add an `ungroup` statement after `summarise` (`summarise([...]) %>% ungroup() %>% arrange([...])`). Honestly, after having worked with colleagues who sent me Excel files and what you describe, it sounds like you may just have duplicate columns to begin with...)

Comment: Saved my career again. Much appreciated, both ways worked.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data types may not be numeric. Hence the `invalid 'type' (character)` part of the error message.

One way to check your data types (in R there are many ways, [this R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/explore-your-dataset-in-r/) covers several other options) is via `summary` and `glimpse`.

Applying these to the in-built starwars dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
data(starwars)
summary(starwars)

     name               height           mass          hair_color         skin_color
Length:87          Min.   : 66.0   Min.   :  15.00   Length:87          Length:87
Class :character   1st Qu.:167.0   1st Qu.:  55.60   Class :character   Class :character
Mode  :character   Median :180.0   Median :  79.00   Mode  :character   Mode  :character
                   Mean   :174.4   Mean   :  97.31
                   3rd Qu.:191.0   3rd Qu.:  84.50
                   Max.   :264.0   Max.   :1358.00
                   NA's   :6       NA's   :28

glimpse(starwars)

Observations: 87
Variables: 13
$ name       <chr> "Luke Skywalker", "C-3PO", "R2-D2", "Darth Vader", "Leia Organa",...
$ height     <int> 172, 167, 96, 202, 150,...
$ mass       <dbl> 77.0, 75.0, 32.0, 136.0, 49.0,...
$ hair_color <chr> "blond", NA, NA, "none", "brown",...
$ skin_color <chr> "fair", "gold", "white, blue", "white",...
```

This shows a clear difference between the character and numeric data types in the dataset. If a column of your dataset should be numeric but has been stored as text, then you can use `as.numeric` to convert it.

E.g. Contrast the following results

```r
# make a column incorrectly character
starwars2 = starwars %>% mutate(mass = as.character(mass))
# view incorrect data
glimpse(starwars2)
# view corrected data
glimpse(starwars2 %>% mutate(mass = as.numeric(mass)))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I thought of this too, but when I perform summary and glimpse(rd_data1), it shows "Number of Points" column as numeric (dbl) along with listing the min, median, mean etc. Would I still need to convert into numeric just in case?

Comment: I just noticed the error message references Total_Points which isn't an input from the original data, but rather a new column I want to add to the table, the same applies for Total_time. I'm starting to think summarise function may not suited for what I'm trying to do.